# XPathDocument Error Will not write to file c#

Tags: xpath

```
private void SetValueToDocumentByXPath(XPathDocument doc, string xpath, string value)
    {

        var nav = doc.CreateNavigator();
        var it = nav.Select(xpath, nameSpaceManager_);
        if (it.MoveNext())
        {
            it.Current.SetValue(value);
        }
    }
```

Since I have changed the document coming in as a parameter I am getting this error:

Additional information: Specified method is not supported.

I would like to Edit the doc coming into the function